# Creating an anti-Trump, moderate Republican white woman in her mid-20s but would like to know how to do it authentically

Tags: racism

I've always been interested in writing about people in America even though I am not American and don't want to live in America. I'd like to ask about how to properly write such a person. Keep in mind  it's **kind of for an erotic story so don't take it too seriously.**

The character I am trying to write is a moderately-Republican white woman, in the South, in her mid-20s. Basically, she's a person who's part of the [Ambivalent Right Political Group of America](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2021/11/09/ambivalent-right/). That means that she is someone who:

- Occasionally leans Democrat but only like a quarter of the time
- Feels coldly toward Donald Trump
- Rejects the idea that Donald Trump won the 2020 election
- Feels ambivalent to both parties but has a more negative view on the Democrats
- Is less politically engaged
- Favors smaller government
- Favors legalization of (some) drugs
- Supports abortion legalization
- Believes government regulation harms businesses
- Has some racist views
- Ambiguous to same-sex marriage
- Believes in bipartisanship and working together

I'm trying to basically write a character with the following traits:

- A white woman in her mid-20s who finished college, is earning $100,000, is relatively fit, lives in the South

The reason why I'm just trying to get ideas on how to write her properly is because **I'm eventually going to write her having an affair, with a non-white older man and boss, and then having both her and him cheat on their respective partners**. I want to realistically or authentically write her personality and hypocrisy. I'm just trying to write this woman as authentically as possible and would like some advice on how I should properly do it.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to do so? My goals is to show that she's going to be using at least some of her characteristics in my story and the beliefs are occasionally going to come into play or be shown the paper.

**How do I authentically make or represent her on the page?**

Comment: This is far too broad to answer here.

Comment: To authentically portray this person will require a lot of research, ideally personal interviews or participant observation with people who fit this description - and probably some who don't, because you can't authentically represent one kind of person if you're inauthentically representing everyone they interact with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it seems to be asking what to write rather than how to write (technically). I'm also thinking the answer might not be of use to that many other users on the SE.

Comment: Or, I could be misreading an unnecessarily long and complex question. Maybe if you edit it down to the core question? Is it about character research? Showing character on the page? Writing relationships? Etc. There could be more than one question and then you should post more than one question. I don't think we have any relevant limitations on the number of questions you can post... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the "has some racist views" you might want to look into the ideology of the American Libertarian party which is a third party that generally spoils for Republicans than it does for the Democrats.  The parties views are best summed up as "Socially-Liberal, Fiscally Conservatives" though one gag T-Shirt I saw summed it up as "Libertarian:  I believe married lesbians should be able to defend their weed farms with guns."

Libertarians are generally minarchist as opposed to anarchist and typically believe that SOME government is necessary, but we have TOO MUCH government as it stands.  Generally the Libertarian believes the chief duty of the government is preventing someone from violating the rights of another and that private industry is more efficient and better able to handle certain tasks than the government, but what tasks are private sector domain vs. public sector domain can lead to internal arguments among themselves. On the whole, they generally believe that the government should not intervene in businesses or ban goods unless it is absolutely necessary.

The only way you could hit "has some racist views" is that Libertarians generally oppose Affirmative Action on the grounds that it is anti-mericratic.  Generally, they don't care about the color of skin than they do about the ability to perform the job.  They wouldn't mind about the skin color of the safety inspector at a nuclear plant, but that persons race shouldn't factor into him getting the job.  But if the white guy is a better safety inspector than the black guy, it should go to the white guy because he's better.  If the reverse is true, it should go to the black guy.  Superficially opposing Affirmative Action can seem "racist" but the argument they have is "what does skin color have to do with the job that would trump ability?" does achieve the goal that affirmative action is trying to achieve.

As a rule, their attitude on diversity is "you do you, boo" and that they are fine with you celebrating your beliefs and ideals so long as you don't force someone else to celebrate with you.  If you think you should go to church every Sunday morning, so be it... but don't force the NFL to cancel football for people who don't want to go church and watch sports on Sunday morning instead.

Hell, some Libertarians who believe marriage is between a man and a woman are still for gay marriage because they realize gays want legal protections afforded to married couples and the government should not interfere with how two private people interact... so remove government rules on marriage and let people work out those details with contracts and wills.  Then call it whatever the hell you want... I might think you're wrong, but who am I to force you to believe what I do?  (Note this is pretty much how they feel about drugs or guns.  Just because I don't like those things, it does not mean I should stop people who do like those things only if they are preventing people from living their lives without them).

Comment: See my post again please

Comment: @ColonizeroftheSun Could you be a bit more explicit about why you don't think this answers your question? Simply asking them to read the question again isn't necessarily going to help them understand what it is you want from them that they haven't provided.